# how to add csrf token into dropzonejs - javascript style - laravel 5.1

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, dropzone.js, csrf-protection

I have successfully sent a csrf token using dropzone but using jquery style, now I don't want to use any jquery in my code I want to use javascript style to get the csrf token. I tried using below code but it keeps on giving me the tokenmismatch error,

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file,xhr,formData) {
            // Show the total progress bar when upload starts
            var folname = document.getElementById('folname').value;
            var token = document.getElementsByName("_token")[0].value;

            formData.append('folname',folname);

            formData.append('_token', token );
        });
```

this is the code that is working using jquery.

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file,xhr,formData) {
            // Show the total progress bar when upload starts
            var folname = document.getElementById('folname').value;
            formData.append('folname',folname);
            formData.append('_token', $('input[name="_token"]').val() );

        });
```

any advice is appreciated. thanks guys.

Comment: Did you debug ``document.getElementsByName("_token")[0].value``? Does it contain anything? How do you place token in your view?

Comment: yes, its value is undefined. my csrf token is like this <form>  {!! csrf_field() !!} </form>

Comment: Might be that you try to access item before it exists? Is your javascript after field declaration? If will be undefined if you run before element without onLoad check. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/uxrfovcs/

Answer (score 0):

Plain old inline javascript variable perhaps? Placed before all scripts possibly at the head

```
var csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
...

// js file where dz related code is residing
...
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file,xhr,formData) {
    // Show the total progress bar when upload 
    var folname = document.getElementById('folname').value;
    formData.append('folname',folname);
    formData.append('_token', csrf_token);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. unfortunately this didn't work. It still return TokenMismatchException. also tried moving the declaration of csrf_token inside the event, still returns an exception. I also tried using {!! csrf_field() !!} instead of {{ csrf_token() }} I still got exception.

Comment: maybe you're passing undefined value of _token in your request? it would be nice you'd provide more parts of your code

Answer (score 0):

Guys thank you for leading me to the right path. I found the problem, I have two elements with "_token" name. so when debugging it returns 'undefined' error.

this code now works.

```
var token = document.getElementsByName("_token")[0].value;
```

my csrf token declaration is like this

```
<form name="post_form" id="post_form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="/post">
{!! csrf_field() !!}
<!-- other code input boxes -->
</form>
<!--my dropzone code is below the form-->
<script>
// dropzone code here
</script>
```

the solution is either I use the token in my meta tag to my dropzone submission or change the name of the meta tag name from "_token" to something else. 
so for this, I choose to use the meta tag to my dropzone code and it's now working. please see below for the solution.

I added a meta tag in my header with "_token" name.

```
<html>
    <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
         <meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}"/>

    </head>
```

and in my footer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajaxSetup({
           headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have use the meta tag token value instead. here's what I did.

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file,xhr,formData) {
            // Show the total progress bar when upload starts
            var folname = document.getElementById('folname').value;                
            var token1 = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')['_token_'].getAttribute('content');                
            formData.append('folname',folname);    
            formData.append('_token', token1 );
        });
```

let me know if I should add anything else to make the post more useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve it.

--- **FIRST** (easiest) ---

```
<form method="POST" action="/your/url/here" class="dropzone" id="upload-files" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('POST') }}
</form>

<script>
    $(function() {
        Dropzone.options.uploadFiles = {
            paramName: 'document_files',
            maxFilesize: 3,
            init : function() {
                this.on("success", function(file, response) {
                    // file uploaded successfully
                });
            }
        };
    });
</script>
```

--- **SECOND** ---

Using dropzone in this way, you can place your dropzone inside another form.

```
<div class="dropzone dropzone-previews" id="dropzone-upload-documents"></div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        // in this case is important that autoDiscover  = false
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

        $("#dropzone-upload-documents").dropzone({
            paramName: 'document_files',
            maxFilesize: 3,
            url: "/your/url/here",
            init: function() {
                this.on("success", function(file, response) {
                    // file uploaded successfully
                });
            },
            sending: function(file, xhr, formData) {
                formData.append("_token", "{{ csrf_token() }}");
                formData.append("_method", "POST");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```